# import ClickHouseHook in airflow 1.10.12

Tags: python, airflow

I try to import class **ClickHouseHook** from **airflow.hooks.clickhouse_hook**

```
from airflow.hooks.clickhouse_hook import ClickHouseHook
```

This is no problem. No import errors here.

But when I try:

```
import airflow.hooks.clickhouse_hook
```

I have an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.hooks.clickhouse_hook'

And I can't understand how it works? I have no module named **clickhouse_hook** in directory **airflow.hooks**, but how can I import class **ClickHouseHook** without error in this way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ClickHouse` provider in Airflow.
I assume you are using [clickhouse plugin](https://github.com/whisklabs/airflow-clickhouse-plugin)
thus the `clickhouse_hook` file is not in `airflow/hooks` folder because it is not part of Airflow.